# installing mod_security2.so on apache2.2.21

Tags: apache, security

I installed **apache2.2.21** and I need this specific version, I'm trying to load **mod_security2**.

The apache server is 32bits and is running on windows 8 64bits.

I did everything possible to get the job done, but I couldn't, can anyone help me?

I put mod_security.so in modules directory, and edited httpd.conf file to load the module but when trying to start the server, it gives me this message:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 126 of C:/Apache2.2.21/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Apache2.2.21/modules/mod_security2.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you describe what you did? `everything possible` is not informative.

Comment: I downloaded the file mod_security-2.8.0-win32.zip from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/ site, and get mod_security2.so from it and copied it to my modules directory, and copied the the file yajel.dll to my bin directory in apache, I uncommented LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so, and add LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so to httpd.conf file,
also, the files libxml2.dll and pcre.dll are missing from bin directory in my apache server, I download them and added them to bin directory.